# Gently stretching a lightly sprained ankle

Tags: recovery

I went over on my ankle (inversion) about halfway through a 5k run. Seemed ok at the time but 24h later I can feel the muscle 'pang' when I walk on it. Currently it's not overly sore but I know that if I keep putting weight on it, it will get worse.

I've taken the day off work, but it got me thinking. Should I try and do light stretches or just rest the ankle completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO!**

A sprain is when the connective tissue is damaged, or over-stretched, but not broken.  It takes time for a sprain to properly heal, and until it does your joint stability is compromised.  Stretching, light or otherwise, will only make matters worse and prolong the healing time.

The best thing to do for a sprain is to let it heal.  Ice it, compress it, and stay off of it.  I've found that a light compression brace worn all day can be very helpful for getting through the work day and helping the joint heal a little quicker.